# Как передать номер строки и столба массива в функцию с последующими операциями над этими значениями?

Tags: javascript

Пишу тетрис на js с использованием массива. Проблема в том что мне нужно как то передать номер ряда и строки элемента(блока) массива в функцию, чтоб уже производить какие либо операции над ним. В общем вот с коментариями -

```js
let tetrisSpace = [ //сам массив
  [1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
];
let showDisplay = () => { // вывод в консоль для отладки
  console.log(tetrisSpace[0][0], tetrisSpace[0][1], tetrisSpace[0][2], tetrisSpace[0][3]);
  console.log(tetrisSpace[1][0], tetrisSpace[1][1], tetrisSpace[1][2], tetrisSpace[1][3]);
  console.log(tetrisSpace[2][0], tetrisSpace[2][1], tetrisSpace[2][2], tetrisSpace[2][3]);
  console.log(tetrisSpace[3][0], tetrisSpace[3][1], tetrisSpace[3][2], tetrisSpace[3][3]);
};
   //дальше идет функция которая будет перемещать мою единицу(блок) в массиве при нажатии кнопки

let moveNewBlock = (array[y][x]) => {  //array[y][x] - так делать нельзя! Но я просто не знаю как иначе(((
  addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 65) {
      array[y][x] = 0;
      showDisplay();
      return array[y][x-1] = 1;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 68) {
      array[y][x] = 0;
      showDisplay();
      return array[y][x+1] = 1;
    }

  })
};


moveNewBlock(tetrisSpace[0][0]); //здесь задаются кординаты перемещаймого обьекта, по идее он должен быть в лупе до тех пор пока единица не дойдет до конца
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let moveNewBlock = (array, y, x) => {/* */};

moveNewBlock(tetrisSpace, 0, 0);
```